# AzureDevops build step passed even when Octopus build failed due to space issue on server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

We are using AzureDevops integrated with Octopus Deploy. Currently, Create octopus release step in AzureDevops showed as passed even when it failed in Octopus due to space issue on server. Any idea how to force AzureDevops to show this as failed step as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that Azure DevOps pushes the packages to Octopus, and you've created the release but not asked it to check in on the status of the deployment.

I have an Azure pipeline building, packaging and pushing to Octopus and it looks like the below:

[Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ekry.png)

I have it create an Azure Release which deals with Creating the Release, Deploying to Dev, Test and lastly Production as below:

[Azure DevOps Release Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m5RS.png)

I'd recommend in your Create Release and Deploy step to "Show Deployment Process" as this will pipe the logs from Octopus to Azure DevOps and mark the Azure DevOps job appropriately. Box below:

[Azure DevOps Show Deployment Process button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WoCq.png)

Please let me know how you get on.

Thanks